# Threshold switch

Tags: transistors, switches, voltage-regulator

I'm looking for a threshold switch which sets the output voltage to Vin, only when Vin > 5V and sets the output to zero otherwise.

I tried the circuit below but it does the opposite of what I want. It sets the Vnode1 = Vin when Vin < 5 and sets Vnode1 to almost zero otherwise.

[image]

How can I achieve the desired circuit?

Comment: define the transfer function and tolerance. It is not inverting

Comment: Which implies 2 inversions with Vref including a series switch, PFET or PNP

Comment: Choose Supply tolerance then set switch to lower tolerance.

Comment: What does the load to this circuit look like? What load can the input accept without significantly affecting the input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something likethis perhaps.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuHYsB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Jasen has given a good answer. Here I will try to explain why your circuit does work in a reverse manner. Here is your circuit but I have drawn it in Multisim for my convenience.

[image]

Neglect XMM1, XMM2, and XMM3, those are multimeter. Additionally, I have provided a switch connection for ON/OFF purpose.

In this circuit, the input source of 7V is used for both the base voltage and collector voltage. You have connected 5.1 Zener voltage rated diode 1N4733A in series between supply and base of the transistor.

***Scenario 1(Below threshold):***

Now, consider the switch S1 is opened ***(in your case you can take it as a voltage is below the threshold level)***. Then the supply will not be passed to the base of the transistor. Because an input voltage is below the threshold level (5V) that is set by the Zener diode here which will not turn on until the supply reaches its Zener voltage of ~5V. So, when you measure a voltage between Node 1 and Ground, here multimeter XMM1 measures that voltage it will show 7V and there will be no current flow or very minimal current in terms of nanoampere current will flow via collector to ground. Here is the relative circuit diagram.

[image]

When we see the circuit, it is clear that Zener diode is not kicked in and the node voltage is same as input supply.

***Scenario 2(Above threshold):***

Now, the switch is closed (i.e) ***voltage reaches beyond the threshold limit of 5V.*** Since the condition is met, Zener diode starts to conduct so that the transistor gets turned on. Hence, it starts to conduct and the current will flow through the collector to emitter and to the ground. Since the load is the resistance of 10 ohms, the current flow through it will be,

I2 = V/R - I1 (current to the base)

I2 = 625 mA (as shown)

The voltage drop across the load R1 will be I2 * R1 approximately 6.25V. So, the Node voltage you are measuring only in millivolts, not the one you expect.Here is the simulation of this scenario.

[image]

Hope this answer helps to some extent!